Impact of r squared value on a linear regression equation output
I have a linear regression equation which goes something like this
y = B0 + B1x1 + B2x2 + B3x3 + ....Bnxn
Where:
y is my dependent variable and
xn are my independent variables
I am generating this equation using statsmodel library in python.
I also get r squared as model's output.
What I need to do next is calculate min and max values of y based on min and max values of all my independent variables.
I do know that, higher the r squared value, higher is the accuracy of regression.
Lets say y = 10 if I put max values of x1 till xn and r2 = 70%
In this case, will y = 10 will be justified or do we say y = 10 but with +/- 30% variation since r2 = 70%
I am not exactly sure how we use the regression equation after considering the impact of r2.

Hi, welcome to stackoverflow! Unfortunately, I am not sure what you mean by "calculate the min and max values of y based on min and max values of all my independent variables.". in the rest of the question you sound like you are looking for a confidence interval? Additionally this sounds off-topic for Stackoverflow. You might get more luck on cross validated since this is a statistics question (although I am not sure I understand it correctly)
